# SQL statement only runs when page is refreshed, not on initial view

Tags: php, mysql

So I have attached a few view counters to pages on my website, and one of the just will not work. It only updates the attribute 'views' when the page is refreshed, not on the initial load for the user. This is of course a problem because I cannot track page views if the user must refresh each time they view an album. 
Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE path='" . $albumPath . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $albumName = $row['name'];
    $views = $row['views'];
    $id = $row['id'];
}
$views = intval($views) + 1;
$sql = "UPDATE albums SET views='9' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($result);
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you're always setting it to 9?

Comment: `$id` is only going to be the last id from your `album` table. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your last line should be `$result = mysql_query($sql);` instead of `mysql_query($result)`. Also, on your second to last line, don't you mean to set views equal to `$views` instead of 9?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE path='" . $albumPath . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $albumName = $row['name'];
    $views = $row['views'];
    $id = $row['id'];
}
$views = intval($views) + 1;
$sql = "UPDATE albums SET views='$views' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```